# DISABLE all mail functions in ubuntu

Tags: php, email, ubuntu-12.04, sendmail

I have a standard staging environment on a ubuntu server (LAMP),
with a couple of webpages on it.

There are some webpages that send Emails on particular workflow events.

I have to run few tests on the system, but can not allow random emails to fly over and spam the moderators (it happened once).

Disabling the particular part of the code, or adjusting the webpage settings is not good scenario, as the system need to be in a production-like setup, plus there may be in several places (or a fallback scenario if one of the options is disabled) and I can not risk it.

Most reasonable solution I can think of is to simple disable(temporary) all mailing services (commonly used with PHP).

I have full access on the server and basic linux skills.

found this witch looks nice for start:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sendmail stop
```

But I need to know how if there are other possible mail services, 
how to check if they are running,
how to stop them,
how to validate.

I guess the above command will probably be enough... but I would like to hear the opinion of some one with more experience in the subject.

Comment: You might be better off asking this on http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score -1):

I think there's a definite separation of concerns issue here. I can see your reasoning for using the disabling method to avoid adding testing inside your code, but the fact that you have many different pathways to trigger `mail()` is potentially evident of a structural problem in your code.

It's especially important as you build a system to try and keep end points to a minimum - if you decided to alter from using sendmail to a more robust system like `phpmailer` or `swiftmailer` in future you'd have to comb your code to make the change. Whereas building wrappers where you only use `mail()` once in your code and direct other areas to this allows much quicker changes, and removes risk of accidents like this.

In fact for email where testing could have really disastrous results (remember you might not always maintain this code) and spam *a lot* of people a positive switch may be useful:

```
function send_email($args...){
    if (LIVE_EMAIL){
         mail($args);
    }
    else {
         log_email_to_file($args);
    }
}
```

Then elsewhere in a config file

```
define('LIVE_EMAIL',true);
```

Now someone needs to explicitly enable emailing, and you just call `send_mail` whenever you need. It has the added benefit that other people reading the code can really easily see what's going to happen, rather than sending emails and wondering why they're not sending because the server has been turned off - or worse thinking it's turned off but a system update has turned it back on!

I tend to avoid answering questions by suggesting a change in tactics but I feel as you're asking this on a programming site then a suggestion which should help develop your code in a more manageable sense could be useful.